# how to set order by in between two union querys

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT month,sum(pcs) as pcs,sum(carat) as carat,sum(amount) as amount from (
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(StockInwardDate, '%b-%Y') AS Month,
COUNT(*) as pcs,
ROUND(SUM(Carat),2) as carat,
ROUND(SUM(TotalAmount),2) as amount
FROM tbl_sales
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(StockInwardDate, '%m-%Y')

UNION

SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(StockInwardDate, '%b-%Y') AS Month,
COUNT(*) as pcs,
ROUND(SUM(Carat),2) as carat,
ROUND(SUM(TotalAmount),2) as amount
FROM tbl_stock
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(StockInwardDate, '%m-%Y') 
) as  tbl
GROUP BY tbl.Month
ORDER by  tbl.Month DESC
```

This above is my query but **tbl.Month** in order by which is equals to **DATE_FORMAT(StockInwardDate, '%m-%Y')**  But instead of **DATE_FORMAT(StockInwardDate, '%m-%Y')** I want to get order by **StockInwardDate** only this

Is there any way to get This in order by *StockInwardDate*

Comment: If you need to order separate subquery then you must enclose it into the parenthesis. Without them last ORDER BY is applied to whole query. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html -> "ORDER BY and LIMIT in Unions"

Comment: Can you give an example of it @Akina

Comment: You can find an example in the article provided.

Comment: Ok , I will See through it